# Texture Panel Options

Tags: uv

In my texture panel I have several red and white checkerboard Icons. What they  have appeared there for I am not certain as they have no assignment?  Is there a way to delete them as I do not believe they are doing anything? Or maybe they are? How could I tell?
[image: from this stock image you can see the red and white icons]

Answer (score 1):

Those icons show the different textures that have been created for your materials. In this example all of them are empty, meaning that no textures have been created yet.

[image]

There is no way or need to delete them.

Once you add some textures, the window will show a list of all the available textures.

To know which ones are enabled for a particular material check the boxes on the right.

[image]

Comment: That is my understanding also. I just find it odd I suppose that someone felt the need to include empty place holders. Also I was wondering what the logic was as to why that might be, i.e. is it a set up or promt of some sort for another function later on ect. But alas, it sounds like it is possibly just a peculiarity of Blender.

Comment: Don't stress about it.

Comment: @animationprofessor A friend of mine used those checkboxes while rendering planets.  For each one, they enabled the texture(s) they wanted, rendered, disabled those, enabled the next set, rendered, etc.  This allowed the used of just one sphere (and put all of the textures in one location), but completely different results from the rendering.